# elements are hiding behind others

Tags: javascript, html, side-menu

I'm trying to make an html page that that has a map for the main page, and a sidenav for a menu. The problem is that I can't get the sidenav open button to show in front or above the map. It seem that its always behind it, or if I mess with stuff I can make the map disappear and then the sidenav open button is visible and works fine.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <style>/*sidenav*/
      html, body {
          font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
      }

      #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }

      .sidenav {
          height: 100%;
          width: 0;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #111;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          transition: 0.5s;
          padding-top: 30px;
      }

      .sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 20px;
         color: #818181;
         display: block;
         border: none;
         background: none;
         text-align: left;
         cursor: pointer;
         transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
          color: #f1f1f1;
      }

      #myInput {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      }

      .main {
          margin-left: 10px;
          font-size: 20px;
          padding: 0px 10px;
      }

      .active {
          background-color: #111;
          color: white;
      }

      .dropdown-container {
          display: none;
          background-color: #262626;
          padding-left: 8px;
      }

      .fa-caret-down {
          float: right;
          padding-right: 8px;
      }

      .sidenav .closebtn {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 25px;
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-left: 50px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
        .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
        .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
      }
      </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>//this is the map stuff//
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHJveWIiLCJhIjoiY2pkb3F0cmJnMHA0YTJ4cXB3Mjc0Y3g0eCJ9.3Myq7AzC4yxR8hi9Ubchdw';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: [-88.75, 42.15],
        zoom: 8
    });


  </script>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Select Congregation
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div id="myDropdown"  class="dropdown-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#Mt. Calm">Mt. Calm</a>
    <a href="#Newark">Newark</a>
    <a href="#Wildwood">Wildwood</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>

<div class="main">

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
          dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
  }
  function filterFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              a[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              a[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "260px";
  }
  function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using z-index?

Comment: I've messed with that and haven't had any results whatsoever. If you could show me where i need to set it, that would be great!

Comment: I'm totally new to html, and JavaScript, so I'll need basic answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the z-index at the navigation menu, try to give z-index to your map itself

`z-index: -1;`

Btw instead of giving google driver, better to write line codes in this directly:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: Perfect! I should have thought of that. Oh well, I'm new but I'm learning! I didn't know if I should put that much code directly in my question.

Comment: you can try to post the important part of your code in stackoverflow, but if you do not know which part is important, just post all your code. It is still better than using google drive(not sustainable, you will have a lot of unused files in your drive AND if you remove it, in the future, when ppl want to see this post, they can no longer access the code)

Comment: Ok! Hadn't thought of it that way. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

In line number 22, change the value of the width to say 200px. Your sidenav appears just fine. Checked with your code.

Comment: He set the `width: 0` because he want it to make it appear by clicking the menu button, try to read the code more :)

Comment: That isn't working on my end. All it does is put the X to close the sidenav in the top right corner.

Comment: .main {
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 0px 10px; position:fixed;
        }

Comment: Add position:fixed under .main css style to make the menu button appear on top.